# New node and custom msg giving a data_class error

Tags: rospy

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have been working on a project for a few weeks everything has gone good until finished my a new node with custom messages. I am very new to ROS  so I am sure that I might be missing one simple step. I have already made other nodes and msgs however this one is giving me problems. I have retraced my steps four times.

I am getting this error when rosrun my node:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/home/onr/catkin_ws/src/furuno_radar/src/ARPA_node.py", line 111, in <module>
        main(sys.argv)
      File "/home/onr/catkin_ws/src/furuno_radar/src/ARPA_node.py", line 104, in main
        ARPAdata = ARPANode()
      File "/home/onr/catkin_ws/src/furuno_radar/src/ARPA_node.py", line 85, in __init__
        self._arpa_info_pub = rospy.Publisher("ARPA_data",RadarARPAInfo())
      File "/opt/ros/indigo/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rospy/topics.py", line 803, in __init__
        super(Publisher, self).__init__(name, data_class, Registration.PUB)
      File "/opt/ros/indigo/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rospy/topics.py", line 138, in __init__
        raise ValueError("data_class [%s] is not a class"%data_class) 
    ValueError: data_class [header: 
      seq: 0
      stamp: 
        secs: 0
        nsecs: 0
      frame_id: ''
    Target: 0
    TDistance: 0.0
    TBearing: 0.0
    TrueSpeed: 0.0
    TrueCourse: 0.0
    RelSpeed: 0.0
    RelCourse: 0.0] is not a class
```

My message is in is own package and CMakeLists.txt and package.xml have been edited.

```
Header header

int32 Target
float64 TDistance #target distance from conning(.0001nm)
float64 TBearing  #target bearing from own ship(.1 degree)
float64 TrueSpeed #target speed(.1kt)
float64 TrueCourse #target course(.1 degree)
float64 RelSpeed #relative speed (.01nm
float64 RelCourse #relitive course (.1 degree)
```

I created a node and made it executable. Here is my node.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import roslib
roslib.load_manifest('furuno_radar')
import sys
import rospy
from arpa_msgs.msg import RadarARPAInfo
from std_msgs.msg import String

import asyncore
import socket

import struct

class ARPANode(asyncore.dispatcher):

    class ARPA:
        radarNo = 0
        target = 0
        ccrpDist = 0.0
        ccrpBear = 0.0
        t_speed = 0.0
        t_course = 0.0
        r_speed = 0.0
        r_course = 0.0
        count = 0
        

    def datagram2ARPA(self, data):
        
        arpa = self.ARPA()
        index = 0
        
        length = struct.unpack_from("<I", data, index)[0]
        index += 4
    
        arpa.radarNo = struct.unpack_from("<I", data, index)[0]
        index += 4
        arpa.targetNo = struct.unpack_from("I", data, index)[0]
        index += 4
        arpa.ccrpDist = struct.unpack_from("<d", data, index)[0]
        index += 8
        arpa.ccrpBear = struct.unpack_from("<d", data, index)[0]
        index += 8
        arpa.t_speed = struct.unpack_from("<d", data, index)[0]
        index += 8
        arpa.t_course = struct.unpack_from("<d", data, index)[0]
        index += 8
        arpa.r_speed = struct.unpack_from("<d", data, index)[0]
        index += 8
        arpa.r_course = struct.unpack_from("<d", data, index)[0]
        index += 8
        arpa.count = struct.unpack_from("<I", data, index)[0]
        
        return arpa
        
    def ARPA2Messages(self, arpa):
        arpa_info_message = RadarARPAInfo()
        arpa_info_message.header.stamp = rospy.Time.now()
        arpa_info_message.TDistance = arpa.ccrpDist
        arpa_info_message.TBearing = arpa.ccrpBear
        arpa_info_message.TrueSpeed = arpa.t_speed
        arpa_info_message.TrueCourse = arpa.t_course
        arpa_info_message.RelSpeed = arpa.r_speed
        arpa_info_message.RelCourse = arpa.r_course
        
        return arpa_info_message
        
    def datagram2ARPAMessage(self, data):
        arpa = self.datagram2ARPA(data)
        return self.ARPA2Messages(arpa)

    def __init__(self):
        asyncore.dispatcher.__init__(self)

        self._radar_ip = rospy.get_param('~radar_ip', '')
        self._radar_port = rospy.get_param('~radar_port', 32123)
        self._arpa_info_pub = rospy.Publisher("ARPA_data",RadarARPAInfo())
      
        self.create_socket(socket.AF_INET,
                           socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
        self.set_reuse_addr()
        self.bind((self._radar_ip, self._radar_port))
          
    def handle_read(self):
        data, addr = self.recvfrom(4096)
        arpa_info= self.datagram2ARPAMessage(data)
        self._arpa_info_pub.publish(arpa_info)
def main(args):
    ARPAdata = ARPANode()
    rospy.init_node('ARPA_node', anonymous=False)
    
    while(not rospy.is_shutdown()):
        asyncore.loop(count=1)
        
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main(sys.argv)
```

Hopefully I gave you enough to work with. Thanks in advanced.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/214666/new-node-and-custom-msg-giving-a-data_class-error/) by [FindogJr](https://answers.ros.org/users/23362/findogjr/) on ROS Answers with karma: 13 on 2015-07-27

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The problem is in creating the Publisher.
You have to pass in the `msg_class` as described [here](http://wiki.ros.org/rospy/Overview/Publishers%20and%20Subscribers#rospy.Publisher_initialization).

You are actually trying to pass in an instantiation of the class, not the class Type.
So do a

```
 self._arpa_info_pub = rospy.Publisher("ARPA_data",RadarARPAInfo)
```

Note the missing `()` at the end.

---

Originally posted by [mgruhler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2647/mgruhler/) with karma: 12390 on 2015-07-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [FindogJr](https://answers.ros.org/users/23362/findogjr/) on 2015-07-28**:
Thanks so much! I knew it was something small I was overlooking. This project has been very humbling. Thanks again!

**Comment by [mgruhler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2647/mgruhler/) on 2015-07-29**:
Glad I could help.
If the question is solved, please accept the answer (by clicking on the check mark next to it). Thx.
So it might help others with the same problem.